# Loading Sounds for SoundPool effectively (Global SoundPool?)

Tags: android, performance, audio, soundpool

I'm creating a game which has a series of sounds to be played on different activities.

Loading the sounds in onCreate hampers the FPS dramatically, I'm wondering is there a more efficient way to load sounds, or a way to create a global soundpool which can be called by the activities.

If I create a public soundpool in my main menu activity, can it be played in future activities?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I always create a separate Sound class (sort of utils), which has all the play, load, unload etc methods. I access these from all of my activities in a static fashion. Make sure that you use the application context to load sounds lest you will end up leaking memory (if you use activity context)